# mac os x leopard mail (3.6.0) : copy/paste html tables

Tags: html, macos, email, copy-paste, osx-leopard

I am developing a website for a customer who sells antiques. All his communications are mail-based and I developed an inquiry reply template for him. Here is a static version of this page: http://thesoulofthesamurai.net/testMail.html

Basically he gets an inquiry mail from a customer in his mail, select the relevant product and copy-paste the HTML content of the template from Safari to Apple Mail. It works fine, until he needs to give information about several items as shown in the following page: http://thesoulofthesamurai.net/testMail2.html

When copying a title or a link from another item, he needs to keep the field title vertically centered. On my system, Snow Leopard with Mail 4.5, I just type enter to get a new line and the text is pasted just at the right place. But on his system, Leopard with Apple Mail Version 3.6 (936) , the text gets placed at a random place, either above or below the cursor as depicted in the image linked below:

[image]

This customer uses Leopard and cannot upgrade to Snow Leopard since his Mac is not Intel-based. I've found users with similar problems but no answer so far: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3271179

Does anyone have any clue to how I could correct the problem, either by changing the template or by getting an upgrade for the mail client?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: EDIT: just got enough rep to add links and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after half a year. The problem is that the cursor was automatically going down at the end of the table cell. The solution was to add two `&nbsp;` after the end of each cell so the copy-paste stays in the same cell.